# How to do this in XSLT using version 1.0

Tags: xslt

A list of numbers corresponding to the factors is defined with this string : 24850973612485097361

The number is flipped and is multiplied for each number with the factor corresponding to its position, 0 corresponding to 10 and all cumulated

For example, for and order having the number 28200703:

The number is flipped giving 30700282

Using the factor string 24850973612485097361 for the corresponding size for the number, the calculation is done as following:

3 x 2 = 6

0 x 4 = 0

7 x 8 = 56

0 x 5 = 0

0 x 10 = 0

2 x 9 = 18

8 x 7 = 56

2 x 3 = 6

Cumulated: 142

Comment: What does your XML look like and why are you doing this in XSLT?

Comment: This is my code
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="WMSxMessage">
  <xsl:for-each select="Envelope">
  <xsl:value-of select="otxsl:var-put('TEST_Number',  Number)"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
Then need to convert the variable TEST_Number based on the question above

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>
    <xsl:param name="factors" select="'24850973612485097361'"/>
    <xsl:param name="accumulated" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$number">
            <xsl:variable name="n" select="$number mod 10" />
            <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring($factors, 1, 1)" />
            <xsl:call-template name="process">
                <xsl:with-param name="number" select="floor($number div 10)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="factors" select="substring($factors, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="accumulated" select="$accumulated + $n * $m" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$accumulated"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Example of call:

```
<xsl:call-template name="process">
    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="28200703"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAF